# iPad Background Image in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, background

So for some reason, whenever I run an ipad simulator in xcode, it does not recognize that it is running as an ipad and pulls the background image for the iphone on the ipad.  This makes it look really stretched and distorted.

Here is part of my code from my ISUtilsPack.h:

```
//device type definition
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
#define IS_IPAD             (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() ==   UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE           (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() ==  UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#else
#define IS_IPAD false
#define IS_IPHONE true
#endif
```

And here is my code from my UIManager.m:

```
//background image
+ (UIImage *)mainBackgorundImage 
{
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-568"];
if(IS_IPAD)
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad"];
return image;
}
```

Every time xcode is pulling the iphone-568 image for the background and not the ipad image even when running the simulator for ipad.  Does anybody know why this is?

Thanks!

Comment: The code under my USUtilsPack.h: 

#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
#define IS_IPAD             (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE           (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#else
#define IS_IPAD false
#define IS_IPHONE true
#endif

Comment: That's too hard to read in a comment. Put it in your question. It looks wrong but its hard to tell.

Comment: Why do you check if `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` exists? Why not simply set `IS_IPAD` to `[UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`?

Comment: sorry im a little confused.  I didn't write this code so I'm trying to figure out a way to fix this and still learning programming.  what would be a better way around UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM?

Comment: I showed you what to do. You don't use UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM.

Comment: ok i just deleted every but left 
(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) #define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)  that seemed to fix it.  THANKS RMADDY YOU ROCK!

Comment: Change it for both, not just iPad.